# VSCode test tab for Django project, Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am fighting for hours with configuring my django project to use this test tab of vs code with pytest.
So for run of
`pytest --collect-only` 
typed in terminal outside my .venv I am getting output as I expect - test are being collected.

But after reloading tests in test tab and looking into output > python I got

```
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
E   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1373
  /Users/dawid/Documents/Projects/parking_test/parking_test/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:1373: PytestConfigWarning: Unknown config option: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
  
    self._warn_or_fail_if_strict(f"Unknown config option: {key}\n")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR parking/tests/test_api.py - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady:...
ERROR parking/tests/test_pytest.py - django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotRea...
```

Here is my *.vscode/settings.json*

```json
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--line-length",
        "79"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        ".", 
    ],
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pytestPath": ".venv/bin/pytest",

}
```

./pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings
python_files = test*.py
```

I tried many solution found mostly on stack/gh but none of them works for me